# Prerender.io not rendering my page properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, prerender

I am facing great difficulty in prerender.io as it is not rendering my page (angularjs app) properly.sometimes it does render properly and sometimes it does not.As I am first using this render.io I am so much confused about it.I have gone through many of the stack overflow questions but no luck.Please somebody help me to figure out the issue.
Thanks inadvance.
my apache code is

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "fsdgfLWfdkjgfkjgdfldgdsjgf"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    <IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

        # Only proxy the request to Prerender if it's a request for HTML
        RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) https://service.prerender.io/http://example.com/$2 [P,L]
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Do you have mod_headers.c, mod_rewrite.c, and mod_proxy_http.c enabled on your Apache server?

Comment: installed prerender in local machine and now it is working fine.but do not know why it was not working if i use https://service.prerender.io/ link

Comment: You could have been sending us a localhost URL or something. Make sure you are sending us a publicly available, DNS accessible URL.

Comment: if my url was not a public url how come it was rendering properly sometimes or partially.